# What happens if all connections from MongoDB pool are busy?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I use standard MongoDB driver for Nodejs, and I have connection pool equals to 5.
What happens if all connections from pool are busy by execution of queries and new one query is occurred? Will be created new connection (6th) for that query or there will be a delay until one of pool connection will be released?

Answer (score 1):

If by "pool size equals to 5", you mean you have set the `maxPoolSize` in the [connection options](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/#connection-options) to 5, then the driver will be limited to 5 connections *per mongod/mongos node*.

This means you can have a total of 5 simultaneous operations to each node.  If you use secondary read preference, you could theoretically have 10 reads and 5 writes in flight at the same if you connect to a 3-node replica set.

If the maximum number of connections are already in use, and additional operations will need to wait for a connection to become available.

Note that the default maxPoolSize is 100 in the current version of the node.js driver.